# [C]Convert Decimal IP To Dotted Decimal Notation

Tags: c, endianness

I got the following Decimal IP: "3232235876" it represents "192.168.1.100"

I got it in the following way:

```
   //GET IP
        if (gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("%s","host not found");
        }

        struct hostent *phe = gethostbyname(hostname);
        memcpy(&addr, phe->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(struct in_addr));

        //Convert IP to Decimal notation
        sprintf(decResult,"%u", addr);
        sprintf(decResult,"%u", htonl(atoi(decResult))); 

But now is my question how do I reconvert it to the Dotted Decimal Notation?
```

I know it's done with 'inet_ntoa' function but I first need to get '3232235876' converted something else and then I need to convert that to addr.

To both those questions I don't know the answer :/

Kind regards.

Comment: Is that ip being sent as a string (e.g. 10 characters in your example), or as a literal number (4 binary bytes)?

Comment: @user611588 I still don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JerryCoffin "*The first octet could be 3 or 32*" What do you mean ? The number `3232235876` represents one and only one address.

Comment: I'm sending files via DCC(IRC Protocol) and IP need to be represented like this.

Comment: Fill in 3232235876 at  http://www.subnetmask.info/ at 'Enter the decimal TCPIP Address:' and you will see that this is correctly: 192.168.1.100.

Comment: For me to be able to receive the file I need to set up a socket and convert it back to the IP but I don't know how to do that

Comment: @JerryCoffin Please check my explanations above :)

Comment: @JerryCoffin: `123123` would be `0x0001E0F3` and this would represent only and unambiguously 0.1.224.243 as the IP address is simply a 32 bit value with each octet being one part of the address. The number `3232235876` is hex `0xC0A80164` which represents 192.168.1.100.

Comment: Yup -- I didn't read his code carefully enough. My apologies.

Comment: So i'm still stuck with the same problem of the conversion :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `inet_ntoa` to convert the address into a string:

```
if (gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname)) == -1) {
    printf("host not found");
    return;
}

struct hostent *phe = gethostbyname(hostname);
if (phe == NULL) {
    printf("Could resolve %s!", hostname);
    return;
}

struct in_addr **addr_list = (struct in_addr **)phe->h_addr_list;
char *addr_str = inet_ntoa(*addr_list[0]);
```

You can also iterate the list of addresses like this:

```
for (int i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) {
    printf("%s ", inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]));
}
```

See the example code in [this gethostbyname man page](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html). Note that `gethostbyname` is deprecated as it doesn't work with IPv6. You should use `getaddrinfo` instead. Again, [see the man page for example code](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getaddrinfoman.html).

Comment: THanks for your reply,Is it possible to have a function where I only have to input the decimal form ("3232235876")? Because what if the hsot is not in my network? And I'm stuck with only "3232235876"?

Comment: `long addr = 3232235876; printf("%d.%d.%d.%d", (addr >> 24), (addr >> 16) & 0xFF, (addr >> 8) & 0xFF, addr & 0xFF);`

Comment: Depending on where that value came from, you might need to filter it through `ntohl` first.

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean you want this? `long addr = ntohl(some_other_long);`

Comment: The problem is ntohl doesn't accept long, it only accepts in_addr, and the problem is That I can't convert the "3232235876" into an in_addr.

If you see in my code example there is a value "addr" before I convert it the value is: "1677830336" so I first need to convert "3232235876" to "1677830336" and then use ntohl on "1677830336" to get the correct result

Comment: Ok i'm going to bed now zzzz gonna have a fresh look at this in the morning

Comment: Solution & credits go to : http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/143350-convert-decimal-ip-dotted-decimal-notation.html#post1069583

Comment: I have no idea about which `ntohl` you are speaking, but the POSIX definition for this function is `uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);`. It means *network-byteorder to host-byteorder long*. You don't need an `in_addr` here anywhere if all you've got is the number. But if you *do* have a `in_addr` then yes, `inet_ntop` is the solution.